# spring request parameter is nested json validation fail

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDrmI.png)I have a request like this:

```
@Controller
public class Test {

    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping("/s")
    public ResData test(@RequestBody @Valid ResData resData){
        System.out.println(resData);
        return resData;
    }
}

@Data
class ResData{

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    Message MSG;
    int code;
}

@Data
class Message {
    @NotBlank(message = "s1 cannot be blank.")
    String s1;
    String s2;
}
```

but when I test it with post some data like this:

```
    {
  "MSG":{
    "s1":"  ",
    "s2":"ss2"
  },
  "code":"200"
}
```

it just cannot recognize:

```
    {
    "code": 10004,
    "msg": "参数校验失败",
    "exceptionMsg": "校验失败:MSG：must not be null, ",
    "body": null
}
```

However, when I change the "MSG" to lowercase "msg", it just worked.
But my situation need the paramter come here is in Uppercase,
could someone tell me the truth?
thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend lowercase of property naming, but you can use `@JsonProperty` annonation to tell Jackson actual Json property is uppercase

```
@Data
class ResData{

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    @JsonProperty("MSG")
    Message msg;
    int code;
 }
```